# Почему я не могу получить параметр из url (api/users/параметр)

Tags: php, rest

У меня возникла проблема, я пишу свой первый RestAPI, и проблема в том что я не могу получить параметры из url, мне нужно получить uuid из url uuid/айди

В итоге мне дает ответ **Unknown GET endpoint**
буду благодарен за ответ.

```
// ...
$request_uri = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
$endpoint = end($request_uri);

// GET
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    switch ($endpoint) {
        case 'uuid':
            $uuid = null;
            if (preg_match('/^\/uuid\/(\d+)$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)) {
                $uuid = $matches[1];
            }
            CheckUUID($uuid,$conn);
            break;
// ...
        default:
            // Обработка запроса для неизвестного ресурса
            echo "Unknown GET endpoint";
    }
}
```

как я пробовал решить проблему:
Менял $endpoint на **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']**

и менял **/^/uuid/(\d+)$/** на **/^/uuid/(.+)$/**

Comment: Причем тут preg_match если сами пишите что дефолтный кейс кидает...

Comment: @InDevX Верно, прошу прощения.